# Rails 4 datetimepicker and cocoon gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

Hi have problem with cocoon: `https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon` and datetimepicker`:http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/`. When I add through cocoon new nested field my calendar not showing up. I think that I must user cocoon after:insert event in my javascript file but I tried every way and this is not working.
This is my views:
costs.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for [:partners, @car], url: wizard_path do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :costs do |cost|
    = render 'cost_fields', f: cost
  #links
    = link_to_add_association '+', f, :costs
  = link_to t('cars.back'), previous_wizard_path
  = f.submit t('cars.next'), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

and my cost_fields partial:

```
.nested-fields
  %table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.dupa
    %thead
      %th.field
        = f.association :cost_type
      %th.field  
        = f.input :netto_price
      %th.field
        = f.input :document_number

      %th.field
        = f.association :vat  

      %th.field
        = f.input :type_of_cost
      %th.field
        = f.input :date, as: :string , :input_html => { :class => 'date' } 
  = link_to_remove_association "X", f
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As this [post](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/186) eludes, this is because the dynamically added elements are not yet in the DOM.

Try to add a class or id before your nested simple fields (this will already be in the DOM), e.g.:

```
#container
    = f.simple_fields_for :costs do |cost|
        = render 'cost_fields', f: cost
```

Then in your javascript file:

```
$(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
    $('#container').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
       $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    })
})
```

Also, I've used this [datepicker gem](https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails), which allows you to generate a wrapper input/custom date/time fields

```
= f.input :date, :as => :date_picker
```